# Android: Infinite loop during Google Login

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

My app has been live using Google login for a few years now. I reworked the implementation a few months ago with no issues until recently.
Now, a few weeks ago, login has stopped working. When I attempt it, the login never finishes, but stays in an infinite loop, displaying the "connecting" screen over and over.

- internet connectivity is ok
- this happens to many users (not sure if it affects ALL Google login users)
- I have tried clearing the cache of Google Play services
- the Google API client is still connected
- I have tried updating all relevant google libraries to the most recent versions
- I see this on Android 6 - not sure if other versions are affected

Before I post my code, I want to point out that the login never returns. The callback is never reached until I actively cancel the login (at which point it behaves as expected. I also want to emphasise again that my code has been in place for quite some time before this occurred - maybe something changed on Google side...

I'm out of ideas and in dire need of help. Any ideas?

### API client creation in `onCreate`:

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = googleSignInOptionsBuilder
        .build();

googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this,
                new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(
                            @NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Logger.error("Google API connection failed");
                    }
                })
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
        .addApi(Games.API)
        .build();
```

### Actual Sign-In method:

```
public void signInWithGoogle() {
    logToServer("Google Sign-In Started");
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi
            .getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent,
            GameConstants.GOOGLE_REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
}
```

### Callback (never touched)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int response,
        Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, response, data);

    if (requestCode == GameConstants.GOOGLE_REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi
                .getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleGoogleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has this issue, this is how to fix it:

You probably forgot to switch the Google authentification on Firebase

You simply need to login to console.firebase.google.com --> Click on Authentification on the left --> Click on Sign-in Method --> Select Google and toggle the switch to activate.

Comment: I have this switch on. If I install the app through Android Studio, it works. But through the GooglePlaystore, it wont let me in. Keeps on asking to select a gmail account